# Mongoosedb: query by username

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Problem Question: I am using MongooseDB with Nodejs and I have user schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userEmail: String
});
```

how would I query using the userEmail?

I tried following but no result. On my `postman` i get cast to ObjectId failed error

```
router.get('/:userEmail', function(req, res, next) {
   User.find(req.params.userEmail, function (err, userDetails) {
     if(err){
       return next(err);
     }res.json(userDetails);
   })
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a query object or document that has the `userEmail` property and a value from the `req.params` object. In your case, this would be:

```
router.get('/:userEmail', function(req, res, next) {
    User.find({ "userEmail": req.params.userEmail }, function(err, userDetails) {
        if(err){
           return next(err);
        }
        res.json(userDetails);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this syntax

```js
router.get('/:userEmail', function(req, res, next) {
   User.find({"userEmail":req.params.userEmail}, function (err, userDetails) {
     if(err){
       return next(err);
     }res.json(userDetails);
   })
 });
```

You have to put condition on which field you want to query data.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your error "ObjectId failed error". However, I am adding another answer to give you more options.

The following things are slightly different from other answers:-

1) **"lean()"** is used to ensure that you will be returned a plain JavaScript object

2) Excluded the "_id" from JSON response though I am not sure whether you need the "Id" in the response. This is just to check whether "id" in response is causing the problem.

```
router.get('/:userEmail', function(req, res, next) {
    User.find({"userEmail": req.params.userEmail}, {"_id":false}).lean().exec(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        console.log(users);
        res.json(users);
    });
});
```